# Cross-validation and weights with glmnet

Tags: cross-validation, glmnet

Are any weights supplied to [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)`::cv.glmnet` taken into account for the calculation of the figure of merit (AUC for logistic regression in my case) on the "held-out" dataset, or only used directly in the fitting?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the answer to the same question and I took a look into the code (v1.8-2) in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html .

The file "cv.elnet.R" (in your case cv.lognet.r) contains the relevant pieces of code.

> cvraw=switch(type.measure,
>
> "mse"=(y-predmat)^2,
>
> "deviance"=(y-predmat)^2,
>
> "mae"=abs(y-predmat)
>
> )
>
> **cvm=apply(cvraw,2,weighted.mean,w=weights,na.rm=TRUE)**
>
> **cvsd=sqrt(apply(scale(cvraw,cvm,FALSE)^2,2,weighted.mean,w=weights,na.rm=TRUE)/(N-1))**

So the package does use the weights in the computation of the figures of merit even on the held-out data. (You will find similar lines in cv.lognet.r as well.)